# call C++ member function from the string input format

Tags: c++, generics

suppose i have a simple C++ class :

```
class Calc
{
    private:
            int a;
    public:
            Calc(){
                    a = 0;
            }
            void seta(int a){
                    this->a = a;
            }
            int geta(){
                    return a;
            }
};
```

Now, suppose, in main i create a object of this class, and take two inputs from user : `var_name` which is name of instance variable in string format, and `action` which is **set** or **get** in string format. For ex : if var_name = "a" and action == "get" , then i should be able to call geta() fn. Is there any way to achieve this in C++.

pls dont provide `if..then..else` kind of soln. I want to write a generic code which need not be updated as more members are added in class Calc.

Comment: Nope, there's no langauage supported way of doing this. You're trying to do something at runtime that is baked in at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically modify C++ types. However, it sounds like you just want a way to set and read attributes. You don't need to modify your class structure for this, there are other alternative solutions. For example you could use an `std::map`:

```
class Calc
{
    private:
            std::map<std::string, int> attributes;
    public:
            Calc(){}

            void setAttr(const std::string& name, int value){
                    attributes[name] = value;
            }
            int getAttr(const std::string& name){
                    return attributes[name];
            }
};
```